# Influxdb2 Python API: Path not found

Tags: python-3.x, influxdb-python, influxdb-2

I have a working InfluxDb2 server and, on a Raspberry Pi, the Python client library.
I've generated the the tokens in the server UI and copied an all-areas one into the Python. The test bucket is set up in the UI too. In the Python program I have this:

```
bucket = "test"
org = "test-org"

# 
token = "blabla=="
# Store the URL of your InfluxDB instance
url="http://10.0.1.1:8086/api/v2"

client = influxdb_client.InfluxDBClient(
   url=url,
   token=token,
   org=org
)
```

Followed later by:

```
p = influxdb_client.Point("my_measurement").tag("location", "Prague").field("temperature", 25.3)
write_api = client.write_api(write_options=SYNCHRONOUS)
write_api.write(bucket='test', org='test-org', record=p)
```

I've overcome the not-authorized but now, whatever I do, I end up with this:

```
influxdb_client.rest.ApiException: (404)
Reason: Not Found
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'X-Influxdb-Build': 'OSS', 'X-Influxdb-Version': 'v2.2.0', 'X-Platform-Error-Code': 'not found', 'Date': 'Tue, 26 Apr 2022 14:35:50 GMT', 'Content-Length': '54'})
HTTP response body: {
    "code": "not found",
    "message": "path not found"
}
```

I've also gone back to Curl which gives me not authorized problem with the same parameters. Any help appreciated, beginning to regret trying to upgrade now.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `/api/v2` in your `url` parameter, just `url="http://10.0.1.1:8086"`

See https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-python#getting-started

Comment: Thanks, struggling with the rest but this bit works, at least!